# NSLOOKUP to iOS 9 device can't find host name

Tags: ios, networking

[Updated]

I want to get an iOS device's host name by ip address from command line

I think I can use NSLOOKUP tool on Mac, but I'm getting

nslookup 10.0.1.2
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find 2.1.0.10.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN

The 10.0.1.2 is ip of an iPhone.

Is there any special on iOS for DNS host name resolution?

Comment: That would only work if you registered a PTR DNS record for the iOS device, which is extremely unlikely and not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking:

Swift:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().name
```

ObjC:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for response, but I'm looking for getting host name from Mac or Linux in the same LAN

Comment: ah. My bad. I assumed you were looking for the hostname of the device being used.